Is the curve $y^7=x^2(x-1)^2$ hyperelliptic?
When playing around with genus $3$ curve $X$ which has an automorphism $\sigma$ of order $7$. Using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, one find the map $X\to Y:=X/\langle\sigma\rangle$ is a degree $7$ map with $3$ ramification points on $Y$ of index $7$. Also $Y$ should be of genus $0$, so we get $X\to\mathbb P^1$. So by some process, the equation of $X$ is equivalent to $y^7=x^a(x-1)^b$. Here the ramification point is $0,1,\infty\in\mathbb P^1$.
Assuming $X$ is projective and smooth, which means that $X$ is a normalization of the compactification of the above plane curve. By a classification, there are only four non equivalent cases: $(a,b)=(3,1),(2,2),(2,1),(1,1)$. In cases $(3,1),(1,1)$, one can show the curve is birationally equivalent to $y^7-1=x^2$ easily. And in the case $(2,1)$, we get the famous Klein curve with $168$ automorphisms. But what happened in the case $(2,2)$?
Is there a way to determine whether the curve in that case is hyperelliptic or not?

Changing variables via
$$x = \frac12 + \frac{X}2, \qquad y = Y^2 ,$$
puts the curve in Weierstraß form,
$$X^2 = 4 Y^7 + 1$$ (the right-hand side and its derivative have no common roots, hence the right-hand side has no multiple roots), hence the curve is hyperelliptic.
In this case a substitution can be guessed by inspection, but one can check directly in Maple whether an algebraic curve is hyperelliptic using the routine
F := y^7 - x^2 * (x - 1)^2;
algcurves:-is_hyperelliptic(F, x, y);

We can compute the Weierstraß form of $F(x, y) = 0$ and a coordinate transformation with
algcurves:-Weierstrassform(F, x, y, Y, X);

The ordering of the new variables, $Y, X$, yields an expression of the form $X^2 - G(Y)$ for some polynomial $G$ (though for our $F$ the procedure gives a different $G$ than we gave above).

Your change of variables looks to have a typo.
